# Object Messages are not getting deserialised in Active MQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am getting below error while trying to connect to ActiveMQ 5.15.9 and fetching the message.

[2019-07-16 09:25:38.61] ERRORDTL [1563269138610]javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build the body from the content. Serializable class is not available to the broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class com.xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.getObject(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:213)

Just to test in ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/bin/env, I made below entry.

ACTIVEMQ_OPTS="$ACTIVEMQ_OPTS -Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=*"

and restarted the MQ, but still, I am getting the same error. 
Is the above-used configuration correct? Do I need to use setTrustedPackages or setTrustAllPackages at client side as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment so I post here.

Have you tried to print the system property to ensure that it's the correct one ?

For the client side, the documentation says :

> On the client side, you need to have this same mechanism [...]

It also gives an example of code :

> The setTrustAllPackages() allows you to turn off security check and trust all classes. It’s useful for testing purposes.

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
factory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
```

You should write this for both the producer and the consumer.

Comment: Does this option need to be set at both side, server and client? Do I need to put the Jar file containing the culprit class into ActiveMQ lib folder to set it in class path?

Comment: In fact I don't think that it should be available to the broker, only for clients. I've edited my anwser.

Comment: I have the legacy code for consumer of Active MQ. I can't introduce "factory.setTrustAllPackages(true);" over there. Is there any other way around like some configuration through which I can go through.